# Where can I find the parser for `bitcoin.conf` files?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development, bitcoin.conf

I have read [bitcoin.conf Configuration File](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/911a40ead256b8849166cff1b745b9c9898e2da8/doc/bitcoin-conf.md) which mentions: *The configuration file is a plain text file and consists of `option=value` entries, one per line. Leading and trailing whitespaces are removed.*

So which of the following are valid:

- `option=value`
- `option=value`
- `option =value`
- `option=value`
- `option = value`

?

I know I can try the above options. However, that brings me to the original question: Where can I find the parser implementation of `bitcoin.conf` files that Bitcoin Core uses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So which of the following are valid:

All of them, as the parser does trim whitespace before and after the string, and before and after both the name and value after splitting them.

> However, that brings me to the original question: Where can I find the parser implementation of bitcoin.conf files that Bitcoin Core uses?

Config file handling can be found in `src/util/system.cpp`, with the main function being `ReadConfigFiles`. The options are parsed in `GetConfigOptions`.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful.